# Multiple faults on Joomla installation

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I have previously installed several different Joomla installation at the same hosting company without any major faults that couldn't be corrected quickly. Though I must say that I now find myself lost and don't know where to turn.. So here I am.

I have mulitple issues that I believe is all connected somehow.

1. Can't upload Images using the Media Uploader (Image size too large) though everything is set up correctly (max_file_size etc.) in PHP configurations and Joomla config.
2. Can't upload any other files in the Extension Manager either, since it says my PHP temp folder is not set. Though it is set, and writeble, have permissions etc. Also more than triplechecked the path, by FTP upload PHP-files to write out and verify the absolute path.
3. When I save something in the Global Configuration, it says my "Configuration.php" file is not writable. Permission is set to 777 even! If I go back and check, my settings is saved though it just said it couldn't save to the file?
4. Even tried to change to FTP-upload to see if I could bypass the fault somehow, tried both by setting it in Global Settings and by downloading the config file, change it manually and then re-upload it via FTP. No luck there either, seemed to just ignore my settings..

Updating Joomla seems to go just fine though, just updated to 3.4.1 to see if it made any difference but no. Running on PHP 5.6 right now though my hostingcompany just said they will downgrade to 5.4 to see if can make something change.

Otherwise, the website is fully functional! You can browse as usual, and write blogs etc. Though, not upload anything. Saving other settings work fine though. Should also mention that the website worked locally 100% before uploaded to the current server.

Any ideas where to start looking? Been Googling for the last 8 hours!

Answer (score 0):

My webhost downgraded my PHP service to 5.4 instead, which solved all problems. Weird.